# Setting cookie SameSite=None doesn't work on Chrome / JSP、JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, jsp, cookies, samesite

I am working on a JSP(tomcat6) application. (domain is different)

I'm trying to set the same-site attribute to `None` because The cookies have disappeared after more than 2 minutes due to the new version of the chrome browser. (Release date for a fix is February 4, 2020 per: https://www.chromium.org/updates/same-site)

#### I tried to solve the problem in the following ways but is still not working

- `response.setHeader("Set-Cookie", "user=test;HttpOnly;Secure;SameSite=None");`
- `response.setHeader("Set-Cookie", "HttpOnly;Secure;SameSite=None");`
- `document.cookie = "witcher=Geralt; HttpOnly; SameSite=None; Secure";`
- `<iframe src="https://service3.smartcapsule.jp/disp/ONECLICKCOMM.do"></iframe>`
- `By using Pop-up windows`

#### Code is here

```
            document.form1.division2.value   = 1;
            document.form1.division3.value   = 1;
            document.form1.division4.value   = 1;
            document.form1.pan.value         = 4322423434232342;
            document.form1.expiryDate.value  = 0222;
            document.form1.jspName.value     = 'index.jsp';
            document.form1.method            = "post";
            document.cookie = "HttpOnly; SameSite=None; Secure";
            document.form1.action            = http://service3.smartcapsule.jp/disp/ONECLICKCOMM.do;
```

#### Header is here

```
<html><body>
host=localhost:8080<br>
connection=keep-alive<br>
content-length=90<br>
cache-control=max-age=0<br>
origin=http://localhost:8080<br>
upgrade-insecure-requests=1<br>
dnt=1<br>
content-type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded<br>
user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4252.0 Safari/537.36<br>
accept=text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9<br>
sec-fetch-site=same-origin<br>
sec-fetch-mode=navigate<br>
sec-fetch-user=?1<br>
sec-fetch-dest=document<br>
accept-encoding=gzip, deflate, br<br>
accept-language=en,q=0.9,q=0.8,ko;q=0.7,ja;q=0.6,q=0.5<br>
cookie=SameSite=None; Secure; aspGroupId=00000000; _ga=GA1.1.371271115.1600306707; _gid=GA1.1.1473986481.1600822923; JSESSIONID=15BA5A77A80B2C93969A44FE9371B135; _gat_UA-71516129-3=1; _token=8b234c913616b70c05100bb7fc141a33; _gat=1; arp_scroll_position=2986.363525390625<br>
</body></html>

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<html><body>
host=localhost:8080<br>
connection=keep-alive<br>
content-length=384<br>
cache-control=max-age=0<br>
origin=null<br>
upgrade-insecure-requests=1<br>
dnt=1<br>
content-type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded<br>
user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4252.0 Safari/537.36<br>
accept=text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9<br>
sec-fetch-site=cross-site<br>
sec-fetch-mode=navigate<br>
sec-fetch-dest=document<br>
accept-encoding=gzip, deflate, br<br>
accept-language=en,q=0.9,q=0.8,ko;q=0.7,ja;q=0.6,q=0.5<br>
</body></html>
```

#### If I don't change browser properties, how should I fix it?

```sh
disable 「SameSite by default cookies」 in chrome://flags
```

---

#### 「20200924」I tried the following, but the cookies was still lost

```
Cookies.set('name', 'value', {
    sameSite: 'none',
    secure: true
})
```

```
response.setHeader("Set-Cookie", "user=mcmd;HttpOnly;Secure;SameSite=None");
```

```
document.cookie = "witcher=Geralt; SameSite=None; Secure";
```

```
public void doGet( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response ) throws ServletException,IOException {
   response.setContentType("text/html;charset=Windows-31J");
   PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
   out.println("<html><body>");
   Enumeration e = request.getHeaderNames();
   while( e.hasMoreElements() ) {
       String name = ( String )e.nextElement();
       out.println( name + "=" + request.getHeader( name ) + "<br>");
   }
   out.println("</body></html>");
}

document.cookie = "<%= s_cookies %>";
```

```
document.cookie = "witcher=Geralt; SameSite=None; Secure";
```

```
res.setHeader("Set-Cookie", "user=mcmd;HttpOnly;Secure;SameSite=None");
res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");
res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials","true");
```

```
crossDomain=true; withCredentials=true;Authorization; Max-Age=60*60*3600
```

```
<iframe src="https://service3.smartcapsule.jp/disp/ONECLICKCOMM.do"></iframe>
```

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
```

```
<script>
    const apexUrl = 'localhost:8080';
    const forwardUrl = 'https://localhost:8080';
    alert(window.location.host);
    if (window.location.host === apexUrl) {
      window.location.host = forwardUrl;
    }
</script>
```

```
Google reCAPTCHA
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To edit a cookie, set its value, and then add it to the response.
and never forget to change the ExpiresDate.